# Android Studio: App skips MainActivity and land on SecondaryActivity on launch

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, ide

My app isn't behaving as intended by skipping the main activity (AuthenticationActivity) and landing on the secondary activity (HomeActivity). If my code is correct, it's supposed to start AuthenticationActivity and land the user on WelcomeFragment if not logged in, or on HomeActivity if user is logged in. This is the code for the AuthenticationActivity:

```
package com.android.MyApp.main;

import com.android.MyApp.R;
import com.android.MyApp.authentication.fragments.WelcomeFragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

import com.android.MyApp.authentication.Constants;

public class AuthenticationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    //Applying layout to activity
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
        pref = getPreferences(0);
        initFragment();
        initActivity();
    }

    private void initFragment(){
        Fragment mFragment;
        if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){
            initActivity();
        }else {
            mFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }


      private void initActivity(){
          //Starting HomeActivity from Authentication Activity if user is logged in.
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, so really could use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in Authentication activity's onCreate method you have(i guess mistakenly) called "initActivity()" method.

In Which you have started HomeActivity.

See your initActivity code:

```
 private void initActivity(){
          //Starting HomeActivity from Authentication Activity if user is logged in.
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Remove this method calling from onCreate() or put some condition here if user is loggedIn already then move to HomeActivity.

Comment: Oh I don't know how I didn't pick up on that one, thank you! When running the app now it's landing me on a blank page. I think it's probably a problem in the xml files, but I'll figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Post your activity_authentication xml code also, then we can figure out whats going on.

Comment: Thank you for offering help! I think I fixed the problem, I had to change a few things in my AuthenticationActivity xml and its fragments.